# Float for input parameter for lambda function in amazon

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I looked at documentation but couldn't find an answer for that. I am trying to add "rating" of type "float" inside custom lambda function. All I see for items are written as {S: date.toISOString()}. Here "S" stands for I think string, but what if I want it to be a float?

```
var aws = require('aws-sdk');
var ddb = new aws.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    
    let date = new Date();

    if (event.request.userAttributes.sub) {

        let params = {
            Item: {
                'id': {S: event.request.userAttributes.sub},
                '__typename': {S: 'User'},
                'name': {S: event.request.userAttributes.name},
                'email': {S: event.request.userAttributes.email},
                'createdAt': {S: date.toISOString()},
                'updatedAt': {S: date.toISOString()},
                'rating': {F: 0}    // is this format true? Or what to do if not?
            },
            TableName: process.env.API_{YOUR_APP_NAME}_USERTABLE_NAME
        };
```

There are so little documentation for this custom lambda function. Or maybe I couldn't find where the details are explained.

Comment: You aren't finding any documentation because you are searching for Lambda function documentation. The question you have is actually about interacting with DynamoDB using NodeJS. The fact that you happen to be running this particular code on AWS Lambda is fairly irrelevant.  I would start by looking at the official docs [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GettingStarted.NodeJs.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type for numbers is "`N`".
This is documented https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBMapper.DataTypes.html.

DynamoDB has just one number type - an unusual decimal floating point type that can be used to represent either floats or integers. So you don't need to tell it if the number is an integer or a float - you just tell it it's a number.

Comment: thank you, you found the document that I was searching for